# UIDatePicker Layout Issue on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I'm developing and application on `iPad` using `UIDatePicker`. On `iPhone` the `UIDatePicker` show fine but in `iPad` it's breaking the layout.

Here's the screenshot:
[image]
Can someone point me what's wrong with the `UIDatePicker` layout issue?

Thanks

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get the exact problem with the demo on which I tried it but if you are using the Date-picker from left edge to right edge then try the following steps.

1) Disable auto-layout and size classes

2) Add Auto-resizing constraints as shown in the screen-shot

[image]

Try it.
Hope it will solve your problem

Comment: I've disabled the auto layout. But where is size classes?

Comment: This shows that you might be using older version of Xcode. Xcode 6 and above have size classes. If no size classes are shown then overlook that option.

Comment: Ok so, in the storyboard or xib, you will get the file inspector on the right pane in which under the interface builder document you will get the options of "Use Auto Layout" and "Use Size classes". Both of them should be unchecked. After that go to size inspector in the right pane itself. Here you will get the view Autoresizing option. Don't forget to select the date Picker component in the interface.

Comment: Hope you haven't coded the dimensions in the .m file. Please share the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may associated with the incorrect size of UIDatePicker. Please set the width 320px and the height 216px for UIDatePicker.

Comment: I have set the with to 320px but the label still cropped

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3:
in viewDidLoad()

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = .countDownTimer
datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
```

I use autolayout. The picker is inside table cell. Reproduced in iOS9.